# Key-Value Storage на Си

Tags: c, key-value

Хочу написать элементарный key-value storage на Си с сохранением в бинарный файл(Возможно с шифрованием).
Есть проблема, я думаю, что функция сохранения будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
int save(char* table, void* key, void* value);
```

Но мне не понятно, как читать значение(из бинарного файла) по ключу, учитывая, что ключ и значение могут быть произвольного значения.

P.S.
Если есть какие-либо статьи по написанию своего key-value storage, было бы прекрасно.

Comment: Можно ли windows, Какая у вас цель, если чисто для конфига - то есть хорошие АПИ по работе и ini файлами GetPrivateProfileString и WritePrivateProfileString

Comment: @nick_n_a Просто ради любопытства, попрактиковаться в Си. Понять, как работают NoSQL БД, основанные на key-value.

Comment: Что означает читать из бинарного файла по-ключу или писать в бинарный файл по-ключу? Такого нету, в файл можно просто записать набор байт, либо прочесть набор байт.

Comment: @nick_n_a Ну это понятно, я запишу в файл с каким-то разделителем, скорее всего, просто мне не понятно, как сделать так, чтобы случайно, допустим, в value не попался разделитель, и все не сломалось.

Comment: @nick_n_a В случае со статическим размером ключа, все довольно легко.

Comment: Есть язык, есть технология. Вам нужно определится с технологией и воспользоваться либо готовыми решениями, либо писать самому. Либо брать драйвер или библиотеку для СУБД (можно поискать ту же csv, dbf), либо использовать такую технологию, как сериализация (двоичная). Ещё как вариант, если asciiz вас устраивает - можно использовать sprintf sscanf printf scanf, но всёравно структуру надо продумать.

Comment: @nick_n_a я уже определился, что хочу написать сам, серилизация невозможна в этом случае, структура динамическая.

Comment: Если у вас данные будут постоянной длинны, то возможно сериализацию удастся избежать. Если переменной - то прийдется делать сериализацию вручную (это означает лишь что будет поле размер данных, и надо читать/писать нужное к-во данных).

Comment: @nick_n_a да, хранить размер ключа и значения - хорошая идея, спасибо.

Comment: СУБД очень часто использую "кластерный" вид хранения, его не очень сложно реализовать, но можно. Выбирается размер кластера, например 512 байт. Дальше записывается к-во записей в кластере, сверху идут ссылки на поля внутри кластера, а снизу "задом-на-перед" (можно в любом порядке главное что бы голова не пересекла хвост) вбиваются данные. Размер данных тут равен 512 - sizeof(count) - sizeof(datastuct)*count. Имеет вид к-во, ссылки, свободное место, данные. Такой принцип я видел у firebird, mysql, mssql и многих других.